# sql datefromparts not working as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following code:

```
Declare @indDate date = '1/1/2014'

SELECT  RecordID AS RID,
            Name, 
            Company, 
            PhoneNumber, 
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DateOfInduction,103) AS StartDate,
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DateOfExpiry,103) AS DateOfExpiry
    FROM Records WHERE DateOfExpiry <= DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YYYY,@indDate),DATEPART(MM,@indDate),DATEPART(DD,DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@indDate)+1,0))))
    AND DateOfExpiry >= DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YYYY,@indDate),DATEPART(MM,@indDate),1)
```

Which basically gives me all expiring records for the month of the `@indDate` parameter.

What I am trying to do is add 1 to the month in the DATEFROMPARTS to get next month's values. Now I don't want to just change the `@indDate` to the other month because in the report the date will not be selected but only something like Expires This Month, Next Month, Previous Month, etc.

So if I change the WHERE clause to:

```
WHERE DateOfExpiry <= DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YYYY,@indDate),DATEPART(MM,DATEADD(MM,1,@indDate)),DATEPART(DD,DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@indDate)+1,0))))
    AND DateOfExpiry >= DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YYYY,@indDate),DATEPART(MM,DATEADD(MM,1,@indDate)),1)
```

I get error: `Cannot construct data type date, some of the arguments have values which are not valid.` and I am not sure why, it works fine If I try something like:

```
Declare @indDate date = '1/1/2014'
select DATEADD(mm,1,@indDate)
```

Can anyone see the problem?

Comment: I've never seen such a crazy WHERE clause, what are you trying to do? I doubt you need to resort to such a strange manipulation, there most likely is a better way to get what you are after.

Comment: Why are you doing `DATEFROMPARTS` when you already have date? If you want to add 1 month, you should use `DATEADD(`, modify your question to include expected values.

Comment: Because I am trying to pull records from the first day of the month until the last of a given date. So the first long DATEFROMPARTS gives me something like 31/1/2014 and the second is just 1/1/2014, then I pull records between these two dates.

Comment: why not use: `WHERE DateOfExpiry >= @indDate AND DateOfExpiry < DATEADD(month,1,@indDate)`

Comment: That actually makes a lot more sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your error is coming from trying to create date from invalid date range,

if you run parts of your `DATEFROMPARTS` in the following manner

```
DECLARE @indDate DATE = '1/1/2014'
SELECT DATEPART(YYYY, @indDate)
       ,DATEPART(MM, DATEADD(MM, 1, @indDate))
       ,DATEPART(DD, DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @indDate) + 1, 0)))
```

this generates `2014 2 31` which is not a valid date.

The following three examples will give you all records for previous, current or next month no matter if you passed in `'01/01/2014'` or `'01/15/2014'`

This will give you all records for last month.

```
WHERE DateOfExpiry >= DATEADD(MONTH, -1,DATEADD(dd,-DATEPART(day,@indDate)+1,@indDate)) AND
DateOfExpiry < DATEADD(dd,-DATEPART(day,@indDate)+1,@indDate)
```

This will give you all records for current month

```
WHERE DateOfExpiry >= DATEADD(dd,-DATEPART(day,@indDate)+1,@indDate) 
and DateOfExpiry < DATEADD(MONTH, 1,DATEADD(dd,-DATEPART(day,@indDate)+1,@indDate))
```

Finally all records for next month

```
WHERE DateOfExpiry >=  DATEADD(MONTH, 1, DATEADD(dd, -DATEPART(day, @indDate) + 1, @indDate))
AND DateOfExpiry < DATEADD(MONTH, 2, DATEADD(dd, -DATEPART(day, @indDate) + 1, @indDate))
```

Comment: looks over complicated to me

Answer (score 0):

why not use:

```
WHERE DateOfExpiry >= @indDate AND DateOfExpiry < DATEADD(month,1,@indDate)
```